# Download multiple files without zip?

Tags: zip, sharepoint

I want to download multiple files from a Sharepoint folder to my hard drive. When I select multiple files to download it automatically zips them but our IT does not allow zip files, so nothing happens. Same thing happens if I choose to download a folder. I can download each file individually no problem.

How can I download many files at once without zip?

Comment: This question really belongs in workplace.stackexchange.com, you just need to change the last sentence a bit.

Comment: How would I change the last sentence? Edit it if you care to.

Comment: Having looked out workplace now, I don't see how it is a more appropriate forum.

Comment: I found this site: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276597/download-multiple-files-without-zip

Comment: change it to "IT policy is hindering my work, what should I do?"

Comment: I know nothing about "not allowing zip files" (in particular: nothing about how it works in your case); but if it's by extension then you can try saving as `.txt`. Decent archive managers (e.g. 7-Zip) should be able to recognize zip even if the extension doesn't match. You may or may not be allowed to use a decent program though; or you may hit another restriction when such program tries to unpack. Anyway, the right thing is to work along with the IT, not against them. The real problem is with the policy. If solved right, you will be able to do your job without "shenanigans" with `.txt` or so.